# WordPress Contact form 7 entry to database without plugin

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, wordpress-shortcode

I tried with sort codes to enable database access form contact form 7 but I got failed.
is there any way to handle contact form 7 data's to database without any plugin or add on. I need to finish this through editing the plugin from backend. Can you please help me ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function contactform7_before_send_mail( $form_to_DB ) {
    //set your db details
    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix.'candidate';

    $form_to_DB = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( $form_to_DB )
    {   
        $formData = $form_to_DB->get_posted_data();
        $firstname = $formData['first_name'];
        $lastname = $formData['last_name'];
        $phoneno = $formData['phone_no'];
        
        $data = array('first_name' => $firstname, 'last_name' => $lastname, 'phone_no' => $phoneno);

        $wpdb->insert( $table, $data, array( '%s','%s','%s' ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'contactform7_before_send_mail' );

?>
```